# Cloud 9 and Flask issue with localhost

Tags: python, flask, cloud9-ide

I apologize for any misinformation from the title but I'm really not sure what the issue is. I'm creating a demo project that receives a user's name and age from an HTML form. Then, there are two buttons. One adds the information to an sqlite3 database called `people.db`. The other retrieves one person randomly from the database and displays it.

Here is my code:

```
import os
import sqlite3

from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import render_template
from flask import g

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def hello():
    error = None

    if request.form.get('submit', None) == "add":
        if request.form['name'] and request.form['age']:
            name = request.form['name']
            age = request.form['age']

            database = connect_db()
            cursor = database.cursor()
            sql = "INSERT INTO person (name, age) VALUES ({0}, {1});".format(name, age)

            cursor.execute(sql)
            database.commit()

            return render_template("index.html")
        else:
            error = "Name or age not provided."
            return render_template('index.html', error=error)
    elif request.form.get('submit', None) == "retrieve":
        database = connect_db()
        cursor = database.cursor()
        sql = "SELECT * FROM person ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;"

        cursor.execute(sql)
        result = cursor.fetchone()

        return render_template("index.html")
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host=os.getenv('IP', '0.0.0.0'),port=int(os.getenv('PORT', 8080)))
```

So, the issue is that when I run the program on Cloud 9's c9users.io platform, it attempts to go to `http://project-username.c9users.io:8080/localhost/?name=name&age=22&submit=add`. I don't understand why it's trying to access localhost here. My program's structure is as follows:

```
\website-test
    \templates
        index.html
    hello.py
    people.db
```

So, I suppose it should be returning to the root of the website while performing the desired functionality. How do I achieve that?

Thank you!

Here, also, is my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>WEBSITES</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h2>Please enter your name and age.</h2>
        <form action="localhost/">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name">
            <input type="text"  name="age" placeholder="age">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="add">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="retrieve">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're missing an `app.run()` in your question. Flask only runs on localhost by default. Cloud 9 might detect this, and redirect you

Comment: This looks like it's open to SQL Injection. Look into how you would construct a query in a way that it avoids SQL Injection.

Comment: Also, you're not differentiating between `GET` and `POST` requests. You can do this by comparing `request.method` to see whether it evaluates to `GET` or to `POST`.

Comment: Apologies if I double post comments, I don't see it appearing. I edited in my app.run() statement!

Answer (score 0):

By default Flask run your application on `localhost`. Add below lines of code to end of the file.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

`0.0.0.0` here means, the app will take the host as your `ip` and will be accessible publically. For further reference read here in [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.run).

Comment: I realize I didn't include it, but I have now added my app.run, which comes recommended by C9, I didn't change any of that code. Does it serve the same purpose as the changes you've suggested?

Comment: @Azhraam `app.run()` will work fine here because C9 will handle the `PORT` and `IP` mapping for you. If you are hosting this application on the remote server then use `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Okay, so then is there an issue with that part of my code?

Comment: I think you should not worry about the localhost thing. What you can do to test whether your application is running fine is: you can just display Hello World message on root endpoint and add a seperate endpoint /hello for above task.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. Why isn't this localhost thing a problem? And how do I do that and why would it be effective?

Answer (score 0):

What is in your index.html? Sounds like you have  `action="localhost/"` on the form element

Comment: I do not have a local host action, but I'll edit my HTML into the post

Comment: that is the line which is redirecting the page to http://project-username.c9users.io:8080/localhost/